# I'm getting jquery issue after writing .htacess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm writing .htaccess for my website.
But after writing .htaccess for some pages, I found that redirection is working but css and jquery is not loading properly. I'm trying in localhost (xampp). Can somebody help me getting out from it.

This is my .htaccess file code.

```
RewriteBase /raman/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d



RewriteRule ^newdashboard$ dashboard.php

RewriteRule ^createbook/(.*)$ create_book.php?creatbookfailed=$1
```

Now, for example, I want to go the create_book.php page, then, it will redirect me to the createbook page but the css and jquery is not loading and giving errors. you can see the errors in the screenshot attached.

[image: Jquery Errors]

I removed the .htaccess and then, run with the original path (create_book.php?creatbookfailed=pathmessage). Jquery is working fine.

Can somebody help me to find out what am I doing wrong here.
Or need some more explanation which I missed now, please let me know

Comment: Maybe you should specify the rewrite condition better, currently you're overriding any resource loaded from system folder. That results index.php page being loaded to the script instead of jQuery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to add the base url in my header file . After adding base url in header file (inside head tag), everything is working fine.

```
<base href="https://www.yourbaseurl.com">
```

Thank you for your answer @Teemu

Comment: Setting base would ruin the first rewrite condition, it will never pass because of the `^` at the beginning of the rule.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. It's not header function it's header file.

Comment: I think I didn't. Setting `base` makes browser to request your resources with preceding base, every relative address becomes absolute, hence when the rewrite condition in .htaccess is `^/system`, it will never redirect (`^` means "at the beginning of the URI`.